# Remove duplicate values from an array

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove duplicate values from a multi-dimensional array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php)

I would like to know how to remove the duplicate array values from the following

```
Array (
   [0] => Array ( )
   [1] => Array (
      [0] => 7
      [1] => 8
   )
   [2] => Array (
      [0] => 7
   )
   [3] => Array (
      [0] => 8
   )
)
```

Comment: Ok, wait a moment, please. Seriously, [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: try typing "I would like to know how to remove the duplicate array values" into google, first result. Cool eh?!

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_unique` PHP function.

```
array_unique($variable);
```